# formset use custom button for add or delete objects

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, formset

i'm going crazy with django formset. the part of creating multiple objects in the db works fine, but I can only generate objects via the 'extra' parameter.
I have created two buttons to add or delete objects dynamically but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone explain it to me in a simple way, nothing too complex, or give me useful links to find the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can do it dinamicaly via JS or jQuery only. Django forms are not so flexible.

Comment: okay but things I can do since if I click on create django it takes only the last compiled object and not all of them